# Lookup accounts based on search criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a sheet in a workbook called *lookup*. Here, users can enter a department code in cell B2 and click a "Search" button which will lead them to a sheet called *deptlookup*. *deptlookup* will list all account codes that have the dept code the user entered inside of it in column A and the account code description in column B. Account codes look like ####### - **###** - ## - ###### (bold section is where department code lives in the account code). The formula in column B is working fine, but the formula in column A is not. It is yielding account codes that have different department codes than what the user is searching for. Formulas:

in cell A2: `=IF(lookup!B2="","",lookup!B2)` (gets dept code).

In cell A3: `=COUNTIFS(acct_codes!A:A,"*-"&A$2&"-*")` the account codes are located in a sheet called `acct_codes` a dynamic query refreshes and pulls active acct_codes from a  database.

in cell A4: (starting the list of acct_codes) `=IF(ROWS($A$4:A4)>A$3,"",INDEX(acct_codes!$A:$A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-"&A$2&"-",acct_codes!$A:$A)),ROW(acct_codes!$A:$A)-ROW(acct_codes!$A$2)+1),ROWS($A$4:A4))))` -- doesn't display an account w/ the department code the user searched for.

in cell A5: `{=IF(ROWS($A$4:A4)>A$3,"",INDEX(acct_codes!$A:$A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-"&A$2&"-",acct_codes!$A:$A)),ROW(acct_codes!$A:$A)-ROW(acct_codes!$A$2)+1),ROWS($A$4:A4))))}` Does display account code with department code user searched for.

in cell A6: `{=IF(ROWS($A$4:A5)>A$3,"",INDEX(acct_codes!$A:$A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-"&A$2&"-",acct_codes!$A:$A)),ROW(acct_codes!$A:$A)-ROW(acct_codes!$A$2)+1),ROWS($A$4:A5))))}` (DOES NOT display account with department code being searched for)

in cell A7: {=IF(ROWS($A$4:A7)>A$3,"",INDEX(acct_codes!$A:$A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-"&A$2&"-",acct_codes!$A:$A)),ROW(acct_codes!$A:$A)-ROW(acct_codes!$A$2)+1),ROWS($A$4:A7))))} --does display account code with department code user searched for

AND SO ON..

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or have any suggestions/alteration I can make to this formula?

Comment: Are all of your cells not working? A1: seems ok to me; A2: might have to change the first * to ??????? (as there are two parts where the * might work), leave the second *. A3-A5 I'll have to dig in more to figure out the formula

Comment: @gns100 I used these formulas before except, the `acct_codes!A:A` was specified as a specific range: `acct_codes!A2:A206811` with this go-around, the account codes in the `acct_code` sheet is a dynamic query so, idk how long the range will be at any given time, that's why I've tried to go with the `acct_codes!A:A` approach in these equations. Being that the range is larger, A2 looks fine, SO does A3, I believe. Once it gets down to where the account codes are being listed, starting from cell A4 and onward, that is giving me issues. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: My original answers, A1 should have been A2, and A2 should have been A3

Comment: I'm not sure I'll be much more help, those array formulas are not my strong point. I'm guessing it's trying to create a list of orgs with no space between rows (or some similar google query I did years ago).